# Please reconsider what is an acceptable question

Tags: discussion

Per [What topics can I ask about here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it is not acceptable to ask:

> > questions concerning third party plugins and themes

This restriction should be reconsidered for these reasons.

1. Plugins become orphaned and support via WordPress forums is not available.
2. Because a category of questions may require "detailed knowledge" is not a reason to restrict them out of hand. Plenty of questions on SO require detail knowledge.
3. StackExchange is generally a better support site.

Comment: `support via WordPress forums is not available.` On what basis you have come to this point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Plugins become orphaned and support via WordPress forums is not available.

Stack Exchange system is not a forum and not meant to provide general support.

> Because a category of questions may require "detailed knowledge" is not a reason to restrict them out of hand. Plenty of questions on SO require detail knowledge.

The issue isn't as much how "detailed" knowledge has to be, but how *wide* scope is.

At the moment we limit our scope to: WordPress core, core themes, featured plugins, few closely related projects. That's scope size of a couple dozen items.

Total count of all items in WP ecosystem? *Tens of thousands*.

Practice showed it is simply *not practical* to post a question about something random out of such a wide scope. Probability of an expert with such specific expertise seeing and answering becomes a lottery with unwinnable odds.

> StackExchange is generally a better support site.

Stack Exchange is not a support site.

As per [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) the purpose of our specific stack, as subset of SE network is (emphasis mine):

> With your help, we're working together **to build a library of detailed answers** to every question about theme and plugin development, development and management best practices and server configuration for WordPress.

This might *look* similar to support at times, but goals of the system are simply not meant to *be* support.